# Unable to style links in SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, styling

I am trying to style the `<a href=""></a>` elements in my page. However, the following code isn't working.

HTML

```
<div class="class-name">
    The quick brown <a href="//example.com">fox</a>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.class-name{
    @include mixin-name(1.7rem 5rem, 1.5rem, 300, $fade-white);
}
a{
    &:link{
        color: $fade-white;
        &:visited{
            color: $white;
            text-decoration: none;
            opacity: 0.42;
        }
    }
    &:hover{
        opacity: 0.7;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    &:active{
        opacity: 1;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

On hovering, the underline isn't appearing on the link. Also except for the hover, everything else is running on Safari but not on Chrome. Can anyone help what is going wrong here?

Comment: `a === a:link`, if you do target `:link`, you also have to target `:visited` also, a link can not be `:link` and have a internal `:visited`, meaning, replace the `:visited` state out of `:link` state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran a quick test. Make sure your mixin is defined at the top. And make sure you start your link of with text-decoration none, so you can see it change

I also removed the `:link` - this is a CSS pseudo-class and it only works if your link has  not been visited. Read up on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alink)

```
$fade-white : #eee;
$white : #ccc;

a{
  color: $fade-white;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:visited{
    color: $white;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.42;
  }
  &:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  &:active{
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you SCSS is wrong, and there for the browser will not do the states you provide:

```
a {
   color: $fade-white;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: $white;

   &:visited{
    opacity: 0.42;
  }
  &:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  &:active{
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

The `:visited` state will inherit from `a` declaration